# How to make is not under 'rootDir' check with TS API?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am working with the TypeScript API (3.8). I noticed that there is a check that `tsc` makes which the TS API does not seem to.

When building a program, and if outDir and rootDir are set, tsc will error out if there is an import of a module outside the rootDir, example:

```
❯ yarn -s tsc --outDir dist
api/app.ts:3:8 - error TS6059: File '/Users/jasonkuhrt/hello/services/boo.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/jasonkuhrt/hello/api'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

3 import '../services/boo'
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

However, the TS API does not make this check.

I don't know if:

1. I am doing something wrong
2. There is a bug in the TS API
3. Theere is a missing feature in the TS API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are checking for the diagnostics on the program. I am able to get the diagnostic you describe by checking `ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)`.

**Reproduction Code**

Here's some reproduction code using [`@ts-morph/bootstrap`](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/tree/latest/packages/bootstrap):

```
import { createProjectSync, ts, InMemoryFileSystemHost } from "@ts-morph/bootstrap";

// file system setup
const fileSystem = new InMemoryFileSystemHost();
fileSystem.writeFileSync("/tsconfig.json", `{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "src",
        "outDir": "dist"
    }
}`);
fileSystem.writeFileSync("/src/file.ts", `import "../otherDir/file";`);
fileSystem.writeFileSync("/otherDir/file.ts", `export class Test {}`);

// create project and program
const project = createProjectSync({
    tsConfigFilePath: "./tsconfig.json",
    fileSystem,
});
const program = project.createProgram();

// output diagnostics
const diagnostics = ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program);
console.log(project.formatDiagnosticsWithColorAndContext(diagnostics));
```

Outputs:

```
src/file.ts:1:8 - error TS6059: File '/otherDir/file.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/src'.
'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

1 import "../otherDir/file";
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Ah yes! I looked at all the diagnostic methods on `EmitAndSemanticDiagnosticsBuilderProgram` type but missed/forgot about this static one.

That's the second time you answer my TS API question, really appreciate it @david-sherret! 